# ngx-order-pipe fails to build in angular 16

Tags: angular, angular16

I just did `import { OrderModule } from 'ngx-order-pipe';` in app.module.ts and added it in imports

```
  imports: [BrowserModule, OrderModule,...],
```

and when I did `ng serve`, I am getting below **failed to compile** error
[image]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ngx-order-pipe` is not built for Ivy ([see this issue](https://github.com/VadimDez/ngx-order-pipe/issues/154)).

[Angular v16 has dropped](https://v16.angular.io/guide/update-to-version-16#angular-compatibility-compiler-ngcc-has-been-removed) the support for non-ivy libs.

Comment: what is the alternate ?